# SWIG & PHP 7 - how to pass binary data from C to PHP (non zero-terminated)?

Tags: php, c, swig

C function `getBytes()` internally allocates n bytes (raw data, may include zeroes).

When specifying it in interface as `char* getBytes()`, at PHP side data looks truncated at first zero byte.

What is SWIG way of returning arbitrary binary data (length is known at C side) to scripting languages?
Portable solution is preferred, but PHP is a must.

Comment: I suggest show more, such as full signature of getBytes() and maybe the process steps to build the PHP extension and how you are using in PHP.

Comment: Also return the length as an argument? `char* getBytes(size_t *pLen)` or probably better `size_t *getBytes(char *pData)`.